# Embed Power BI report in Salesforce

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, azure-active-directory, powerbi, salesforce-lightning

I am following the Microsoft blog (link here - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/embedding-a-power-bi-report-into-salesforce/) to embed a power bi report into a visual force page in salesforce. However, the end users do not have a Microsoft account (they will have a salesforce account) and I will be using a different Microsoft account (lets say impersonation account) to connect to Power BI via Azure AD.

When I open the visual force page from salesforce it first goes to the Microsoft login screen and once I enter the impersonation account username and password only then embeds the entire report in salesforce. Is there a way to directly log into Microsoft using the impersonation account from salesforce? (the end users will not have a Microsoft account). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Azure Active Directory B2B and add them as guest user. Image:

[image]